# According to what does GNOME purge the trash "30 days later"?

Tags: files, gnome3, trash

In GNOME 3.18 Settings > Privacy > Purge Trash & Temporary Files, one can configure the desktop environment to automatically empty Trash "after 30 days".
[image]

The description here isn't very clear. Is "30 days" supposed to be 30 days being in the Trash, 30 days after last opening/changing the file, or would all files be deleted together after 30 days without any new activity or new file in the Trash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my tests it should be equivalent to

*empty trash contents every 30 days*

This is what I did:
At 1:45 PM I cleared the trash and set the privacy options to purge after *1 hour* and rebooted the machine, just to be sure. I then deleted two (several months old) files and executed a script that creates a file and moves it to trash - every 12 minutes. At 2:42 PM I *accessed* all files in trash and *edited* some of them. At 2:45 PM they were *all* gone. Half an hour later I created two files, moved them to trash and again edited them while being in the trash. At 3:45 PM the trash was empty again.
I've concluded the system clears the trash every hour removing the files regardless of their age, the time they've stayed in the trash, their access or modification time.
Anyway, you could always ask a question on GNOME mailing list though as you can see from [this bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=689048) the devs themselves appear to be quite confused about it:

> This isn't clear. Does it clear the whole trash:/// contents every X
>   days? Or does it remove trash files older than a certain age?
>
> I'm guessing the latter, so I would call it "remove-old-trash-files".

Comment: I think it would be *safer* to have a rolling purge, i.e. purge only files that were added to the trash 30 days ago and have not been edited since, and run this purge e.g. once per day.  Surprised it's not that way already.

Comment: @Wildcard - well, that was my initial interpretation after reading the `gsettings` schemas description (see `org.gnome.desktop.privacy`). But it's not like that, at least not when setting it to `1 hour` (I doubt that setting it to 30 days would change the behavior). Whether that's safer or not... I don't know. I never cared about stuff in the trash (actually, I don't even use it much - it's Shift+Delete most times).

Comment: I think that only accentuates the point.  Power users aren't likely to use the trash much...except when helping some poor lost soul who is utterly nontechnical to recover his/her files.  Don't tell me *you're* not the tech support for your family members; I won't believe you.  ;)  The whole point of the trash in the first place (vs. immediate oblivion) *is* to protect users from themselves.  If it gets purged two minutes later because the thirty day period happened to finish right then...that's a bit of a step backward, don't you think?

Comment: @Wildcard - well, that didn't occur to me; yes, you're right on all counts.

Comment: Wow, this was the least expected behavior...

Comment: @busukxuan - yeah, I know... but it's like that; you can easily test this yourself if you set the purge interval to one hour.

Comment: Coming across this makes me think there is a pattern where GNOME pretends to have features but they are actually implemented in a way that shows no one involved has ever genuinely used them or cared enough to give the implementation serious/careful thought.